# is_page_template checking in the included file

Tags: wordpress, templates

I need to check if my custom page template is index-with-sidebar.php

I do it like that

```
function index_with_sidebar() {
    echo (is_page_template('index-with-sidebar.php')) ? 'col-md-6' : 'col-md-4';
}
```

In content.php I have

```
<div class="item <?php index_with_sidebar(); ?> ">item</div>
```

And in the index-with-sidebar.php I'm getting the content post format by:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
```

The above function display `col-md-4` instead of `col-md-6` when I'm on index-with-sidebar.php page. If I hardcode the `col-md-6` to the `div.item` it works fine. Seems that the function do not echo the proper value. What am I doing wrong? Can you help me?

EDIT

Before the Loop

```
<?php $g = index_with_sidebar(); ?>
```

In the Loop

```
<?php $e = has_post_format() ? 'content-'.get_post_format().'.php' : 'content.php'; ?>
<?php require(locate_template( $e )); ?>
```

And I can use $g variable in my content-X.php templates :)

Answer (score 0):

If you call the function in the content.php, your page template isn't index-with-sidebar.php, so it's correct that it outputs the *false* answer.

To get a *true*, you can just call the function inside of the index-with-sidebar.php.

Comment: Yes, agree! But then I need somehow to pass the result to the content.php and I do not know how

Comment: How is your template structured? Do you call the content.php from the index-with-sidebar.php?